# Visualization of voxels/octrees in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, voxel, apple-model-io

I want to render Voxel/Octree objects (cubes with different sizes basically) in iOS; so far, I have been looking at SceneKit to perform the visualization. The goal is to render 10 to 15k voxels in a scene like rendering an Octomap for robotics applications (such as: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKNzTg25RM8).

In SceneKit framework we rendered these cube objects with SCCNNode with SCNBox geometry in it. The performance degrades significantly if we use a lot of geometry objects, so we are unsure if we are using the best approach for it, we also discovered MDLVoxelArray for this purpose but have not used it yet. I have not been able to find the proper documentation or references to include it in SceneKit. Can MDLVoxelArray be a solution to visualize voxels properly?